# Web2Py insert into database error

Tags: sql, database, insert, web2py

I am trying to make insert. This is my code:

```
db.define_table('orders',
            Field('idProduct', type = 'integer'),
            Field('quantity', type = 'integer'),
            Field('idUser', type = 'integer'),
            Field('status'),
            Field('order_date'),
            Field('product_price', type = 'integer'))
```

The SQL:

```
sql = "Insert into orders (idProduct,idUser,quantity,status,order_date,product_price) values "
sql = sql + "(" + str(idProduct) + "," + str(idUser) + "," + str(quantity) + ",'cart','" + str(order_date)+ "," + str(product_price)+"')"
```

and I am getting following error:

```
<class 'sqlite3.OperationalError'> 5 values for 6 columns
```

I don't understand what is wrong, because if i remove `product_price`, everything is working.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have extra quote before the last closing bracket. Remove it and it will fix the error:

```
sql = sql + "(" + str(idProduct) + "," + str(idUser) + "," +
str(quantity) + ",'cart','" + str(order_date)+ "," +
str(product_price)+")"
```

Comment: Thanks, i did the same thing before, but my code is broken somewere and it still does not work.

Comment: Another error: <class 'sqlite3.OperationalError'> unrecognized token: "'16-5-2016 11:30,None)"

Comment: It's for the same sql statement? 16-5-2016 11:30 is started with quote, but not closed. And None is not valid sql value. It should be quoted if it is string or probably you're using some uninitialized variable. As far as it's new problem (with probably another root cause), try to open new question.